# Regarding the scons build for iotivity on linux

Tags: iotivity

out/linux/x86_64/release/service/resource-container/src/ResourceContainerImpl.os: In function `bool boost::thread::timed_join<boost::posix_time::seconds>(boost::posix_time::seconds const&)':
ResourceContainerImpl.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6thread10timed_joinINS_10posix_time7secondsEEEbRKT_[_ZN5boost6thread10timed_joinINS_10posix_time7secondsEEEbRKT_]+0xe5): undefined reference to`boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(boost::detail::mono_platform_timepoint const&, bool&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [out/linux/x86_64/release/service/resource-container/librcs_container.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
I am getting this error can anyone help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

do you have all the required libraries installed?

try:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev
```

If you are just getting started with IoTivity I would encourage using iotivity-lite instead of iotivity.  The open connectivity foundation has almost stopped additional developement on iotivity and have switched to iotivity-lite.